# Can not publish Post To WordPress Using WordpressSharp and XmlRpc

Tags: c#, wordpress

i am using WordPressSharp for publish a post to my Wordpress Site with C#

my wordpress site is hosted in my vps (windows server 2008)

i am used example code  in following link

http://abrudtkuhl.github.io/WordPressSharp/

it successfully runned in local pc

but when tested in my vps (windows server 2008)

Error occurred: 
 :CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcServerException: Not Found
   at CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcClientProtocol.ReadResponse(XmlRpcRequest req, WebResponse webResp, Stream respStm)
   at CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcClientProtocol.Invoke(Object clientObj, MethodInfo mi, Object[] parameters)
   at XmlRpcProxy82ec7367-bf26-457b-abee-0249da5fadb3.NewPost(Int32 blog_id, String username, String password, Post_Put post)
   at WordPressSharp.WordPressClient.NewPost(Post post)

I turn off the firewall but The problem is not solved

I need a Solution for My Problem

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find solution

in base url must be used IP no site url

http://ip/xmlrpc.php